WillPopScope to PopScope and TabBarView bugs
I'm having problems with PopScope.
I migrated from WillPopScope to PopScope. My code went from this (internal details have been removed for better visualization):
return WillPopScope(
    child: tabBarPages(),
    onWillPop: () async {
        showExitPopup();
        return false;
    });

To this:
return PopScope(
    child:  tabBarPages(),
    canPop: false,
    onPopInvoked: (value) async {
        showExitPopup();
    });

The summary structure is as follows:
Scaffold -> body: PopScope -> child: TabBarView

With WillPopScope everything was working perfectly, on any of the 3 TabBarView screens, when pressing the Back button, the app was not closed and the Dialog asking if the person would really like to close the app appeared.
But now with PopScope, being on the second or third screen, instead of displaying the Dialog, the screen goes black (indicating that the app has been closed, but without actually closing). Being on the first TabBarView screen, the Dialog appears normally, however, on screen 2 or 3 the Dialog does not appear, and the screen goes black.
I went back to the deprecated WillPopScope and everything worked normally again. What do I do? How do I solve this problem without using deprecated code?

Could you try to fire your showExitPopup fn when didPop is false.
Like this
onPopInvoked: (didPop) async { if(!didPop) showExitPopup(); });

Try this way PopScope -> child: Scaffold -> body: TabBarView

No, it's still the same thing. If you try to exit through screen 2 or 3, the screen goes black.
